# Bootstrap different active class on navbar

Tags: jquery, css, navbar

I use bootstrap and nav bar

I would like to customize the 'active' with a different class.

I did that but I can not seem to finish:

```
$(function() {
$('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
    $this.parent().addClass($this.attr('class').split(' ').slice(0)+'active');

 });
});
```

The idea is to remove the class 'active' and add my class.

Currently :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li class="toto">
  <li class="titi">
</ul>
```

To get :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
 <li class="toto totoactive">
 <li class="titi">
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
 <li class="toto">
 <li class="titi titiactive">
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This isn't a great idea as those classes then become far too specific; you may as well use `id` instead. Why not have a single `active` class, which you can then select via `.toto.active` and `.titi.active` for the respective elements.

Comment: I want a different color for each  <li> when it is active.

I also try css:

.active > .toto {
 background-color:#000;
}

Comment: Exactly, that's what I described. Check the CSS rules I mentioned. Your example there is incorrect as it's looking for `.toto` as a child of `.active` whereas the class will be on the same element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you don't need this.

You can define CSS rules for every element being `active`:

```
.toto.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.titi.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

For example, the first rule will be applied only to the element having both `toto` and `active` classes at the same time.

Now, you can simply apply `active` class:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="toto">
    <li class="titi active"> <!-- .titi.active rule applied -->
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="toto active"> <!-- .toto.active rule applied -->
    <li class="titi active">
</ul>
```